# Font awesome is not working(blank square box appearing) for social media link in my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, fonts

I recently created a Wordpress website where font awesome is not working for social media icon in landing page and for one more icon. But in other pages icons are properly displayed.

Switching to the CDN hosted version isn't working also. The images are not coming only in home page. The icons are visible in other pages of my website.

Below is the snapshot where I have included the cdn version in adminheader.php which is inside  wp-admin folder.

CDN version:

Also, I have tried giving the path of style.CSS

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you modified the wp-admin files? This isn't something I have really seen done before. If you have a header file in your active theme, you should modify that file and stick the CDN version of Font Awesome in it. You could also enqueue it in the functions file. Here's a guide by Elegant Themes showing you what to do.

https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/font-awesome-wordpress

Comment: Hi Carl, I have modified the header file.